# What is the maven dependency to use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer? For a spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project which does NOT USE spring-boot.

Im trying to use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer in my appConfig class to configure a default date format.

I have these two dependencies in already but I'm still getting an error on the ObjectMapper? I am using spring version 4. All the examples for using the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` are using spring boot which seems to not need need a dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>`

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>`
```

Comment: You state " but I'm still getting an error on the ObjectMapper" – which error? Please amend it to your question.

Comment: That is a Spring Boot class so it won't work with regular Spring.

Answer (score 1):

The class is only part of Spring Boot dependencies. If you are determined to not use any Spring Boot dependencies, you will have to look for alternatives, otherwise you can use the following:

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependency . its an alternative for non spring boot projects.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.10.1