# Format date in response JSON from controller

Tags: java, json, spring, date, sap-commerce-cloud

I am returning a *JSON* as a response from the *controller*. I want to format the date fields in this response.

***Controller***-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/call", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SampleDTO get() 
{
    ......
    return sampleDTO;
}
```

***SampleDTO***-

```
{
   "date" : "2020-03-10T08:57:58+0000",
   "text" : "abc"
}
```

I want to format the date field to `dd-MM-yyyy`

To do this I add the `@JsonFormat` *annotation* to the bean class of `SampleDTO`.

***SampleDTO.java*** -

```
import java.util.Date;
public class SampleDTO
{ 
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") 
    private Date date;

    private String text;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") 
    public void setDate(final Date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") 
    public Date getDate() 
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setText(final String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() 
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Still, I am getting this format in the response on my browser.

> "date" : "2020-03-10T08:57:58+0000"

---

***EDIT 1:***

Instead of returning the sampleDTO, converting it to String directly in the code works perfectly fine.

This works like a charm:

```
        SampleDTO sampleDTO = new SampleDTO();
        sampleDTO.setCreated(new Date());
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        return om.writeValueAsString(sampleDTO);
```

Comment: Two recommendations: (1) Don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) In your JSON use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, so `yyyy-MM-dd`, not `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Comment: @OleV.V. : I see `Date` class all over the place in the latest version of Hybris. In my JSON I have a specific requirement to show the date in this format, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check that your `Date` is from `java.util` and not from `java.sql` package. Plus try the following:

```java
@JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: @Farrukh Chishti, above should work, what version of jackson-databind.jar are you using?

Comment: @MOnkey : I am using 2.9.8

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this on the field level and remove from `getDate()` method in your DTO.

Something like this,

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date date;
```

This should work with your current version of `jackson-databind:2.9.8.jar`.

Here is the small example for you:

```
public class ExampleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setDateOfBirth(Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().minusYears(30).toInstant()));

        System.out.println("-- before serialization --");
        System.out.println(employee);

        System.out.println("-- after serialization --");
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = om.writeValueAsString(employee);
        System.out.println(jsonString);

        System.out.println("-- after deserialization --");
        System.out.println(om.readValue(jsonString, Employee.class));
    }
}

public class Employee {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date dateOfBirth;


    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Farrukh Chishti, try once the above changes.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes. Removing the annotation from getter and keeping the annotation on the field intact. No luck!
In my code, the response is parsed automatically in the background. I am not using any mapper explicitly. I am simply returning the response as `return sampleDTO`

Answer (score 1):

There are three levels of how you can solve this date format issue with Spring.

**1) Using @JsonFormat on your date fields**

In this case, you need to use the same annotation in front of all your private date members.

```
public class MyBean{

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date birthday;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate birthday;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

**2) Setting the Default format**

If you want to configure the default date format for all dates in your application, add the following line to the `application.properties` or `application.yml` config file:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work with the Java 8 date types, like LocalDate and LocalDateTime.

**3) Customizing your Jackson ObjectMapper**

This solution works like a charm with Java 8 date types as well.

```
@Configuration
public class ContactAppConfig {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.simpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT)));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)));
        };
    }
 }
```

I suggest you use the 3rd option.

Comment: Approach #1 is not working. Approach #2 will cause system-wide changes which, I don't want. Approach #3: Class `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` is missing in my codebase.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572936/what-is-the-maven-dependency-to-use-jackson2objectmapperbuildercustomizer-for-a

Answer (score 0):

you can use jstl format to format the date :)

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" value = "${date}" />
```

Comment: I want to simply change the format in the Webservice call i.e. in postman